# Removing rows with specific text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to get the combinations of values of columns. For instance,

```py
   UT    Fruit_1 Fruit_2 Fruit_3
0  I1      Apple  Orange   Peach
1  I2      Apple   Lemon     NaN
2  I3  Starfruit   Apple  Orange
```

in this dataframe, I want to combine values of Fruit_* columns. So, the results are (Apple, Orange), (Apple, Peach), (Orange, Peach)...

As you can see, the dataframe has NaN. So, after the combination work, I will delete rows with specific text: 'nan'. By reading some posts related to this task, I made the below code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame([['I1', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Peach'],
                   ['I2', 'Apple', 'Lemon', np.NAN],
                   ['I3', 'Starfruit', 'Apple', 'Orange']],
                  columns=['UT', 'Fruit_1', 'Fruit_2', 'Fruit_3'])

temp1 = df.set_index ('UT')
temp2 = temp1.apply (lambda x: list (combinations (x, 2)), 1)
temp3 = temp2.apply (lambda x: pd.Series (x))
temp4 = temp3.stack ().reset_index (level = [0, 1])
del temp4['level_1']
temp4.columns = ['UT', 'pair']
temp4[~temp4.pair.str.contains('nan')]
```

But, after running this code, I got an error message:

*TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''*

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pandas 0.25 is possible use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with trick for remove `NaNs` in `combinations` by filter out them by `list comprehension with filter`, it working, because `np.NaN != np.NaN` by [definition](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['I1', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Peach'],
                   ['I2', 'Apple', 'Lemon', np.NAN],
                   ['I3', 'Starfruit', 'Apple', 'Orange']],
                  columns=['UT', 'Fruit_1', 'Fruit_2', 'Fruit_3'])

temp4 = (df.set_index ('UT')
           .apply (lambda x: list (combinations ([y for y in x if y == y], 2)), 1)
           .explode()
           .reset_index(name='pair'))

print (temp2)
   UT                 pair
0  I1      (Apple, Orange)
1  I1       (Apple, Peach)
2  I1      (Orange, Peach)
3  I2       (Apple, Lemon)
4  I3   (Starfruit, Apple)
5  I3  (Starfruit, Orange)
6  I3      (Apple, Orange)
```

For oldier pandas versions:

```
temp4 = (df.set_index ('UT')
          .stack()
          .groupby(level=0)
          .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(combinations (x, 2))))
          .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
          .reset_index(name='pair'))

print (temp4)
   UT                 pair
0  I1      (Apple, Orange)
1  I1       (Apple, Peach)
2  I1      (Orange, Peach)
3  I2       (Apple, Lemon)
4  I3   (Starfruit, Apple)
5  I3  (Starfruit, Orange)
6  I3      (Apple, Orange)
```